# c - wrong count result in array

Tags: c

The program simply reads the file count strings and their length. But the counter p of string gives me a wrong result. If I just print the count p the result will be correct but if I print the element a[i][1] (which is supposed to be p) it gives me a wrong result. For an example in element a[0][1] - it prints 12, where it is supposed to be 1.

```
int main(int argv,char* argc[]) {

    FILE *f = fopen("d.txt","r");
    int a[700000][1];
    char str[120];
    int i=0,l,p=0,n;
    while (fgets(str,120,f)) {
        l=strlen(str)-1;
        p++;
        a[i][0]=l;
        a[i][1]=p;
        i++;
    }
    // if I printf("%d",p);  result will be correct
    n=i-1;
    for (i=0;i<=3;i++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[i][1]); //result - 12 6 4 8 
    }

    close(f);
    return(0);
}
```

d.txt

No\0
one\0
is\0
here\0

result will be - 4 2 4 4

Comment: We cannot reproduce this without your input data. Please present your [MCVE] as instructed.

Comment: What is this: 'int a[700000][1];' ??

Comment: int a[5][1]; look better?

Comment: ...because this 'a[i][1]=p;' is UB.

Comment: @alex_mike no, not really:(  The only valid index for the second dimension is [0].

Comment: why? I want to use a matrix a[5][1]  - 5 rows 2 colomns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
int a[700000][1];
```

This defines a 2 dimension array of type *int*, but the 2nd dimension is 1, resulting effectively in a 1 dimension array.

Later on, when you attempt to access elements in the array:

```
    a[i][0]=l;
    a[i][1]=p;
```

The first assignment is fine -- it sets the value in memory that is *i* integers away from the start of the array.

But the second assignment is not correct. The index *1* is beyond the 2nd dimension limit of 1 (0 is the first element, 1 is the second element). Since C does not do run time array limit checking, so this gets translated to setting an element that is *i+1* integers away from the start of the  array.

If you want a 700000x2 array, the declaration would look like this:

```
    int a[700000][2];
```